# setInterval error when changing images

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use setInterval to change images, when the image changes instead of the new image it only shows the alt text. I am a new to JavaScipt so please keep this in mind if you have a suggestion.

```js
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* <![CDATA[ */
 var changePic;
 var pic = new Array(14);
 var curPic = 0;
 pug[0] = "gallery1.jpeg";
 pug[1] = "gallery2.jpeg";
 pug[2] = "gallery3.jpeg";
 pug[3] = "gallery4.jpeg";
 pug[4] = "gallery5.jpeg";
 pug[5] = "gallery6.jpeg";
 pug[6] = "gallery7.jpeg";
 pug[7] = "gallery8.jpeg";
 pug[8] = "gallery9.jpeg";
 pug[9] = "gallery10.jpeg";
 pug[10] = "gallery11.jpeg";
 pug[11] = "gallery12.jpeg";
 pug[12] = "gallery13.jpeg";
 pug[13] = "gallery14.jpeg";

 function change(){
  if (curPic == 13)
   curPic = 0;
  else
   ++curPic;
  document.images[0].src = pic[curPic];
 }

 function startChange(){
  if (changePic != null)
   clearInterval(changePic);
  changePic = setInterval("change()", 1000);
  
 }

/* ]]> */

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="gallery1.jpeg" alt="gallery_pic"/>
 
 <form action="">
  <input type="button" value=" Change " onclick="startChange();" />
  <input type="button" value=" Stop " onclick="clearInterval(changePic);" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I am trying to create a simple slideshow using some images. 
Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `pug` should be `pic` or vice versa. Here is a working example:

```js
var changePic;
var pug = new Array(14);
var curPic = 0;
pug[0] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg";
pug[1] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg";
pug[2] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg";
pug[3] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg";
pug[4] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/5.jpg";
pug[5] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/6.jpg";
pug[6] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/7.jpg";
pug[7] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/8.jpg";
pug[8] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/9.jpg";
pug[9] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/10.jpg";
pug[10] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg";
pug[11] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/12.jpg";
pug[12] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/13.jpg";
pug[13] = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/14.jpg";

function change(){
  if (curPic == 13)
    curPic = 0;
  else
    ++curPic;
  document.images[0].src = pug[curPic];
}

function startChange(){
  if (changePic != null)
    clearInterval(changePic);

  changePic = setInterval(change, 1000);
}
```

```html
<img width="64" height="64" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" alt="gallery_pic"/>

<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="startChange();" />
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="clearInterval(changePic);" />
```

Comment: I feel really stupid. I copy and pasted the arrays and didn't even notice that I made a typo with pug instead of pic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missed between variables pic and pug.
all pug statement should be replace like:

```
pug[0] = "gallery1.jpeg";
```

by

```
pic[0] = "gallery1.jpeg";
```